# JQuery Form Query: Setting field entries in accordance to other fields

Tags: 2010, list, jquery

I have a custom list (serving as a change control form), which I'd like to tweak a little.  my Jquery isn't my strongest suit, hance my asking you guys for help.  I'd like to ask if it's possible to set field values on a form depending upon selections in another column.  Specifically

1. If DateField is Filled, Set ChoiceField to Specific Option
2. If ChoiceField is a Specific Option, Prompt for DateField to be filled out (Can I cater for this in List Validation?)

Hope that's clear, please let me know if not and I'll be happy to try re-explain.

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly all doable with jQuery. My personal preference is to use selectors like `$("input[Title='My Field']")` to get the fields I want. Both should be simple change functions:

```
$("input[Title='My Field']").change(function(){
  $("input[Title='My Other Field']").val("Something");
  //or any other type of logic, like:
  // if ($(this).val()=== "something"){$("input[Title='My Other Field']").val("Something");}
});
```

Point 2 would be something like:

```
$("input[Title='Conditional Field']").hide();
$("input[Title='My Field']").change(function(){
  alert("Please fill out this other field");
  $("input[Title='Conditional Field']").show();
});
```

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for the post. I'm going to try this tomorrow and will mark / ask as I go. Cheers,

Comment: No problem, without seeing your form code and whatnot, these are just general guidelines, the selectors are the key though.